# Set up a simple Phantom / Mocha test for a rendered page?

Tags: javascript, testing, backbone.js, phantomjs, mocha.js

I would like to add tests to my Backbone application, using PhantomJS and Mocha.

I have been following [this tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/testing-javascript-with-phantomjs/). I would like to load a page in my existing Backbone application, and check the title tag is what I expect.

This is my first attempt in `test/test.js`:

```
describe("DOM Tests", function () {
    var page = require('webpage').create();
    page.open('http://localhost:5000/', function () {
        var title = page.evaluate(function () {
            it("has the right title", function () {
              expect(document.title).to.equal('hello world');
            });
        });
        phantom.exit();
    });
});
```

I don't know if my syntax is correct, but anyway, at the moment, when I go to `http://localhost:5000/testrunner.html` I see the following error message:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

How can I fix this? And, am I testing in the right way?

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this by removing the logic for phantom. Your code could possibly be refactored to

```
describe("DOM Tests", function () {
   it("has the right title", function () {
     expect(document.title).to.equal('hello world');
   });
});
```

There appears to multiple problems with your current implementation

- `testrunner.html` most likely does not include the script for `require`.
- `test.js` does not include a `define( function( require ) { //your code here } );`. You can check out [requirejs Getting Started](http://requirejs.org/docs/start.html) for more information.

Also, if you download the [example files](http://nettuts.s3.amazonaws.com/2161_phantom/code.zip) for the site you mentioned, you'll be able to see the complete tests. I recommend carefully reading over the *PhantomJS and Mocha* section on their site again, specifically their `test.js` file under that section.